# How to Configure yii URL manager for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, yii, yii-url-manager

Perhaps this question has already been asked somewhere, but I couldn't find anything suitable for my problem.

I'm creating a website using yii and its URL manager. In my localhost, the URL manager works perfectly fine. But the problem arise after I upload it to a server with subdomain. The domain and subdomain should be `http://tokoandhika.mauinimauitu.com`.

In my localhost, `http://localhost/tokoandhika/catalog/category1` works fine. It will access *actionIndex function* in *CatalogController.php*. But if I access `http://tokoandhika.mauinimauitu.com/catalog/category1`, it will prompted Internal Server Error (PHP Error 500).

What could have gone wrong? Do I need to edit the htaccess file? Or do I need to add more rules for this? Any helpful advice would be much appreciated.

Below is my rules for the URL manager:

```
'rules' => array(
            'category/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>'                      => 'category/index',
            'page/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>'                          => 'site/page/index',
            'gii'                                                => 'gii/default',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'                      => 'gii/<controller>/view',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'         => 'gii/<controller>/<action>',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'                  => 'gii/<controller>/<action>',
            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/id/<id:\w->'      => 'gii/<controller>/<action>/id/<id>',
            'catalog/addtocart/'                                 => 'catalog/addtocart',
            'catalog/detail/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>'                => 'catalog/detail',
            'catalog/<cat:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/<subcat:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>' => 'catalog/index',
            'catalog/<cat:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>'                        => 'catalog/index',
        ),
```

and here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php'; Does your index.php in source Files contain these lines?

Comment: Yes, It's already there

Comment: A 500 status code tells you that there is an error in your code. Check if you can find this, ie by accessing the error log.

Comment: have you checked the log file on server?

Comment: I checked the error log file and no errors are recorded. Weird...